# Tkinter обновление переменной в тексте каждую секунду

Tags: python, tkinter

Имеется окно tkinter, с надписью "Завершение работы произойдет через 15 секунд" и кнопкой "Отмена"
По задумке, переменная "a" должна обновляться каждую секунду и это должно отображаться в окне. Но почему-то при запуске сначала идет цикл, а уже потом появляется окно, в котором переменная уже равна нулю. Как сделать, чтобы переменная обновлялась в окне, а не перед его появлением.

Код:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import time

os.system('shutdown -s -t 25')

tk = Tk()
tk.title('Выключение ПК')
tk.geometry('450x400')
a = 15
text = Label(text='Выключение пк произойдет \nчерез '+str(a)+'  секунд')
while a > 0:
   a -= 1
   time.sleep(1)
   text['text'] = 'Выключение пк произойдет \nчерез '+str(a)+'  секунд'
text.place(relx = .5, rely = .1, anchor = 'c')
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: tk.mainloop() запускает окно, сначала отработает цикл, а потом будет окно. Я tk не особо знаю, но подозрение в этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работать будет, но лучше переписать через класс

```
a = 15
os.system('shutdown -s -t '+str(a))

tk = Tk()
tk.title('Выключение ПК')
tk.geometry('450x400')
text = Label()
text.place(relx = .5, rely = .1, anchor = 'c')

def timer() :
   global a
   a -= 1
   text.configure(text='Выключение пк произойдет \nчерез '+str(a)+'  секунд')
   if(a):
      tk.after(1000, timer)
   else :
      tk.destroy()

timer()   
tk.mainloop()
```